# Version of Xtreme Codejock OCX

Tags: vb6, libraries, ocx

I have a program that uses Xtreme Codejock libraries. My program is in VB6 and I am using 17.3 version for Codejock libraries OCX. 
The problem is to install my program in another computer with Windows 10 with older Codejock libraries installed and when I install it, my program gets crashed.

If I delete old Codejock libraries and try to run my program, it skips the installation of the program that installed the old libraries.

In another computer, without older Codejock libraries my program runs fine.

My Codejock libraries are registered with

```
regsvr32 Codejock.ChartPro.v17.3.0.ocx
```

I need to run my program in computers with older versions of Codejock libraries, what can I do?

EDIT:

The program crash with Error 5 when go to this code

```
Sub AddBarSeries()
  Dim pContent as ChartContent
  Dim pDiagram as new ChartDiagram2D
  Dim pSeriesD as ChartSeries
```

This object are from Codejock.ChartPro.v17.3.0.OCX

Comment: Generally old and new versions of OCX files can both be installed and registered on the same PC at the same time with no issue. Is the problem that your installer sees the OLD files and then skips installing the new ones?

Comment: No, i can install my program. The problem is when I try to execute it.

Comment: But is your installer installing the newest OCX files?

Comment: yes, my installer register newest OCX.

Comment: Can I create an manifest file to tell my program which version of the ocx to use?

Comment: Yes you can, but doing so is a very manual error-prone process. But once done can be a very stable, reliable approach. But I am not sure that is what is required.

Comment: Either the new & old libraries should coexist together happily, or the new ones should effectively upgrade & replace the old ones. Is your code using early or late binding?

Comment: i don't know. How is defined?

Comment: Early binding is when your VB6 project references the DLL or OCX directly (Project menu > References or Project menu > Components). Late binding is when you use CreateObject() in code. Most likely you are early binding if you are using controls from the OCX

Comment: Yes, then early binding

Comment: Question 1: When your installer completes, has it successfully installed & registered the correct OCX file? Question 2: When your program crashes, what is the error?

Comment: 1.- Yes, i can see the file .OCX in Windows/SysWow64 and the register with regedit

Comment: 2.- When program crash, i got Error 5.

Comment: Can you add some more details of this error to your question? What specific line of code does it occur on?

Comment: Install the ocx and dll libraries in your application's folder instead of system32/64/syswow/etc.